# to turn off the texts that appear on the Ubuntu splash screen? Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: software-installation

What should I do to turn off the texts that appear on the Ubuntu splash screen? on the boot screen. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 with khadas VIM4. Texts appearing after the boot logo.

[image: Texts appearing after the boot logo.]

Comment: I want to turn off the texts that appear on the Ubuntu splash screen. on the boot screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your first command, `add-apt-repository`, adds a new repository to the system, a new place from which software can be downloaded. However, after adding the new repository, you need to refresh the list of available packages so that new packages in this repository can be added to the list. You do this with

```
sudo apt update
```

After running that command, you will be able to install `grub-customizer` with `sudo apt install grub-customizer`.

Comment: I do not have to do this with Grub Customizer. I only added it because they had done it using this before. If there is another method, I can hide the texts with it.

Comment: @OzgeH.Durgut then please [edit] your question, explain what texts you want to remove and explain the context (that you want to build your own image). None of this is clear. However, if you want to install `grub-customizer`, you need to run `apt update` after adding the PPA.

Comment: @OrganicMarble yes, so you say, but since you don't explain how or why, that isn't very helpful. Why not post an answer explaining how to add `quiet` into the relevant boot line of `grub.cfg`?

Comment: I edited my question. I think it's more clear now.